# .htaccess rewrite domainnames, save subdomain and parameters

Tags: .htaccess, dns, url-rewriting

i have 2 domains but want use only one.

these some examples of domains...

x://test1.domain1.xx/parameter/1

x://test1.domain1.xx/parameter/2

x://test1.domain1.xx/parameter/3

---

x://test2.domain1.xx/parameter/1

x://test2.domain1.xx/parameter/2

x://test2.domain1.xx/parameter/3

---

x://test1.domain2.xx/parameter/1

x://test1.domain2.xx/parameter/2

x://test1.domain2.xx/parameter/3

---

x://test2.domain2.xx/parameter/1

x://test2.domain2.xx/parameter/2

x://test2.domain2.xx/parameter/3

now i want only use xx.domain2.xx/params... all sub/domains with maindomain "domain1" should be rewritten or redirect. without loose parameters or subdomain.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Explain the problem a little more

Comment: currently you can access my site with both domains domain1.xx and domain2.xx. but now i want use only domain2.xx. that means each person wich came from domain1.xx should be redirected to domain2.xx without loose any params or subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

I tried sometimes an i think i got a solution.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain1.xx [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) http://%2.domain2.xx/$1 [R=301,L]